# AclExtras Warning Error

Tags: cakephp

In [CakePHP 2 book / Acl Tutorial / Part 2](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/simple-acl-controlled-application/part-two.html), I am executing the command:

```
./Console/cake AclExtras.AclExtras aco_sync
```

and I get a warning error:

```
Warning Error: Argument 1 passed to Component::startup() must be an instance of Controller, 
null given, called in 
/opt/lampp/htdocs/acl/app/Plugin/AclExtras/Console/Command/AclExtrasShell.php 
on line 80 and defined in [/opt/lampp/htdocs/acl/lib/Cake/Controller/Component.php, line 119]
```

The acos table gets populated with `NULL` in `model` field and `NULL` in all fields of the `foreign_key`.

How can I fix this error?

[image]

ThAnKs

Answer (score 9):

in AclExtras/Console/Command, please change startup function to :

```
public function startup() {
    parent::startup();
    $controller = new Controller();
    $collection = new ComponentCollection();
    $this->Acl = new AclComponent($collection);
    $this->Acl->startup($controller);
    $this->Aco = $this->Acl->Aco;
}
```

Comment: mustapha might have the correct answer as it appears this code change made it into CakePHP itself. See GitHub: https://github.com/markstory/acl_extras/issues/16